# Canvas Crayon Effect

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, paint

I am willing to Create an effect of Crayon like when user draws a hand free drawing and the effect is been shown in image below :

[image]

I tried Adding opacity and also tried to change pixel color with nearer alpha colors but somehow it is not getting me those shades

After trying some more paint object shades i m not close to 80% of above image

Any clues will be appreciated

I tried to look over ***"Hello Water Color Android App"*** this also does not have shades like above in real time drawing hence even i am not sure if these shades can be achieved with real time user drawings